# Not able to get result value from google translate using phantomjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, phantomjs, google-translate

This is my code to get the google translate of the word am giving in the program.Am using phantomjs to achieve this.

Am passing the "Word:asdasdasd" to the text area with the id "source" and triggering the click event.After that trying to check whether the result value which is wrapped under the newly created span tag or not.For that am checking whether its parent with the id "result_box" has more than one childern. If its a case,then we can say span tag is created dynamically once the value is passed to textarea.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
console.log("Entering the program");
page.onConsoleMessage = function (msg) { 
    console.log(msg); 
};
page.open("http://translate.google.com", function(status) {
    if(status == 'success'){
        console.log("Page loaded "+ status);
        page.includeJs("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js", function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                var data = page.evaluate(function() {
                    $('#source').val("asdasdasd");
                    var ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
                    ev.initEvent("click", true, true);
                    document.querySelector("input[id='gt-submit']").dispatchEvent(ev);
                    console.log("Click on page ");
                                if( $('#result_box').children.length > 0 ){
                                    console.log("New Span included");
                                    console.log("value: " + $('#result_box').val());
                                }
                                else{
                                    console.log("No span");
                                }
                                });
                                console.log("Exiting the program");
                phantom.exit()
            }, 10000);
        });
    }
});
```

[image]

**Output:**

Entering the program

Page loaded success

Click on page

New Span included

value:

Exiting the program

---

My question here is it says new span tag is created but am not able to get the value of it.Its strange.Whats wrong with the above code?.

Please anyone point me the solution.

Thanks in advance

**Update**:[image]

Comment: `value` is mostly for `inputs` or `form elements`.Here you can use `.text()` to get only the text inside it without any html markup

Comment: I tried with `.text()`.It didn't work.Still returns empty

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: No errors in console.But it returns empty when I try to run from my program.check my updated ans for screenshot

Comment: did u try .html() ?? that also show empty?

Comment: @Neha ya it returns empty too.

Comment: Just check in html if there are No multiple tags with same id..!! that can be one reason for empty content. try also to take $(".hps").html().

Comment: This too works but only in the console.But the same doesn't work in the code which I mentioned in the question.whats happening?.I don't get it.

Comment: what i understood u dispatch the event and immediately look for the span may be that time it was not added in the elements, as event is submitting the form, which might take some time. try to add some timeout there. There is also return value of dispatchevent check that : var canceled = !target.dispatchEvent(event); if its useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding points to @Neha,

this worked for me.

```
setTimeout(function(){                           
 console.log("After 5 sec value: " + document.getElementById('result_box').innerHTML);    
},5000);
```

Comment: Hey I tried including it in my program.It didn't work.

Comment: Did u removing the phantom.exit(). Because before the timeout runs, program might exit.

Comment: yes you are right.It works now.But how do i exit the program now?.Am not able to exit aft once it prints the value.The variable is not accessed globally i think so.any ideas on that?

Comment: I got the solution.I wrapped it under another timeout function to exit the program.

Comment: It is better to use promises or provide a callback that will be called when the timeout is done in order to synchronize the exit with the end of the job operation.